# How to remove the inserted page number from url in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am making a blog with Gatsby and have created "paginated pages" in the `gatsby-node.js` file as shown in the image. This makes a new page after a certain number of posts.

Then in my `templates/allPosts.js` file I map through the posts and have a `<Link to={frontmatter.slug} />` for each post. All the links work fine on the first page but after that e.g. on page 2, the page number is inserted into the URL before the slug, but this is not the correct URL for the blog article. I need the page number to not be inserted.

[Creating paginated pages in the gatsby-node.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyxxV.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! kindly share code snippet and not image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the section in the Gatsby docs on [relative links](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#relative-links) you should be able to prefix your slugs with `/..` to remove the page component in your urls.

> The `<Link />` component follows the behavior of @reach/router by ignoring trailing slashes and treating each page as if it were a directory when resolving relative links. For example if you are on either `/blog/my-great-page` or `/blog/my-great-page/` (note the trailing slash), a link to `../second-page` will take you to `/blog/second-page`.

To keep things consistent, you might want to add the page number to the first page too.

Comment: Just tried <Link to={`../${post.node.frontmatter.slug}`} /> and it now works. The page number is now ignored. Thank you Simon!

Answer (score 1):

So, according to what you said, you want to keep the page structure (i.e: `/blog/number/`) but the post `slug` must remove the number, isn't?

Then, on the link to the post, use an absolute URL like: `` <Link to={`/blog/page-title`}> `` instead of `` <Link to={`page-title`}> ``. Note that if you want to remove and use absolute paths you must prefix the links with a slash (`/`). You can also check (because there's no code in your question) if using relative paths such as `../post-title` works for you.

You may want to take a look at [Gatsby's documentation about relative links](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#relative-links).